# cannot read 'map' property of undefined in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a little fun website for looking up recipes using an API and React. Every part of this project worked except and the data would show up in the LiveServer, except when I added the ingredients code, the entire thing fell apart.

**Here is the text of the main App.js file, the part of the code I am wondering about is at the bottom**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Recipe from "./Recipe";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const APP_ID = "e0ca1d82";
  const APP_KEY = "91fbf750ba45172f714b70f2df5512e2";

  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("chicken");

  useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
  }, [query]);

  const getRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setRecipes(data.hits);
    console.log(data.hits);
  };

  const updateSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  const getSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery(search);
    setSearch("");
  };

  // The troublemaker, maybe

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={getSearch} className="search-form">
        <input
          className="search-bar"
          type="text"
          value={search}
          onChange={updateSearch}
        />
        <button className="search-button" type="submit">
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
      {recipes.map((recipe) => (
        <Recipe
          key={recipe.recipe.label}
          title={recipe.recipe.label}
          calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
          image={recipe.recipe.image}
          ingridients={recipe.recipe.ingredients}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**And here is the code that has the error**

```
import React from "react";

const Recipe = ({ title, calories, image, ingredients }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <ol>
        {ingredients.map((ingredient) => (
          <li>{ingredient.text}</li>
        ))}
      </ol>
      <p>{calories}</p>
      <img src={image} alt="" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Recipe;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might not be the solution, but you have spelt ingredients wrong. You spelt it as `ingridients` so it doesn't match the props on Recipe

Comment: You misspelled the “ingredients” prop name: `ingridients={…}`.

Comment: This question can be put on hold as Typo/No Repro.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {ingredients.map((ingredient) => (
      <li>{ingredient.text}</li>
    ))}
```

the error is in this part of code.please check with the ingredients array values when you pass through App.js

make sure you what you pass from here

```
   {recipes.map((recipe) => (
      <Recipe
       key={recipe.recipe.label}
       title={recipe.recipe.label}
        calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
       image={recipe.recipe.image}
       ingridients={recipe.recipe.ingredients}
        />
     ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `useCallback` for getRecipes function and also need to check ingredients is available or not.

This full code is working.

[Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-albattani-fruo7?file=/src/App.js:0-1802)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const APP_ID = "e0ca1d82";
  const APP_KEY = "91fbf750ba45172f714b70f2df5512e2";

  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("chicken");

  const getRecipes = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setRecipes(data.hits);
    console.log(data.hits);
  }, [query]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
  }, [getRecipes]);

  const updateSearch = e => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  const getSearch = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery(search);
    setSearch("");
  };

  // The troublemaker, maybe

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={getSearch} className="search-form">
        <input
          className="search-bar"
          type="text"
          value={search}
          onChange={updateSearch}
        />
        <button className="search-button" type="submit">
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
      {recipes.map(recipe => (
        <Recipe
          key={recipe.recipe.label}
          title={recipe.recipe.label}
          calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
          image={recipe.recipe.image}
          ingridients={recipe.recipe.ingredients}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Recipe = ({ title, calories, image, ingredients }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <ol>
        {ingredients &&
          ingredients.map(ingredient => <li>{ingredient.text}</li>)}
      </ol>
      <p>{calories}</p>
      <img src={image} alt="" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be nice if you check the array before mapping over it like below

```
const Recipe = ({ title, calories, image, ingredients }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <ol>
        {
          ingredients 
            && ingredients.length > 0 
            && ingredients.map((ingredient) => (
                 <li>{ingredient.text}</li>
               ))
        }
      </ol>
      <p>{calories}</p>
      <img src={image} alt="" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: That fixed the error, but it still doesn't show the <li> . Sorry if I am not understanding something basic, I am still learning the basics of coding and I am following a tutorial.

Comment: yes that would not show the `ingredients` because your `ingredients` list may be empty or you might not getting it in right way, try loggin the `ingredients` before `return` part to see if you are getting it in right way, and im here to answer you dont worry!